# Could not find androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4

Tags: android, flutter, react-native

Started getting this error today (without any changes in the project).

```
Could not find androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4
```

It seems this package is no longer available in Jcenter.

Updating to 3.1.5 or 3.1.6 doesn't fix the issue.

This package is part of `react-native-background-downloader`

Answer (score 2):

After some research, the fix is to switch to

```
implementation "com.github.tonyofrancis.Fetch:xfetch2:3.1.6"
```

from https://jitpack.io/#tonyofrancis/Fetch/3.1.6

Source: https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch/issues/586

We had to patch `react-native-background-downloader`

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-background-downloader/android/build.gradle b/node_modules/react-native-background-downloader/android/build.gradle
index 3018efe..95ebb2b 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-background-downloader/android/build.gradle
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-background-downloader/android/build.gradle
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ dependencies {
     //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
     implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
     if (project.properties['android.useAndroidX'] == 'true' || project.properties['android.useAndroidX'] == true) {
-        api "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4"
+        api "com.github.tonyofrancis.Fetch:xfetch2:3.1.6"
     } else {
         api "com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:3.0.10"
     }
```